# Where should I store environment specific settings in react redux app

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-saga

Note: New to React concepts, please do not ignore any conceptual mistakes in question, correct me.

I am building an app using react and redux. I started with [this](https://github.com/coryhouse/react-slingshot) starter kit and made some progress. Now when I need to call my apis, I am not sure where should I maintain my api url and other configurations w.r.t environments.

Say I have a services folder which contains apis.js and this is the module that exports api functions. I am taking some inspiration from the redux-saga real world example app on this. But the API url on my dev will be different from that on the production or staging. so I can't just say

```
const API_ROOT = 'http://localhost:5000';
```

I have two files for webpack config as `webpack.config.dev.js` and `webpack.config.prod.js` but I am not sure if these are the files I should be having my config in.

Or should it be in my redux store as initial state? Or should it be a part of build process where the URL is replaced with the URL of that particular environment?

Comment: One option that I have used before is part of the build process. Reference the API url from some config file within your app, and populate/overwrite this config during your build pipeline with the correct url (this could be based on node parameters for example npm run build --env='dev')

Comment: I support @TMitchell 's suggestion of utilizing the build process to specify configuration. However, I would use `new webpack.DefinePlugin({ API_ROOT: JSON.stringify('http://localhost:5000') })` in webpack.config, so you can specify different values for each environment.